# Any site on the SE network for war stories/discussion?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm interested in reading/knowing about various war related stories. It would also be great to have some healthy discussion around the same.

Any site on the network for the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Any site on the network for the same?

No. Nor do I expect there such a site to ever exist on the network.

Our sites are designed for Q&A - war stories are not questions and are not answers.

We have also found out that our sites are not good for discussion - this is in fact a key feature of the sites these days. No discussions. Period.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current site for war stories nor discussion (with the exception of Meta.SE for the latter), but you could try chat.

You could try the chatroom for Mythology.SE or History.SE for more on-topic-ness.